# Bash: How to stop function execution on error in the `if` statement?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeuo pipefail

func() {
  false
  echo "Should not be here"
}

if func; then
  echo "Test passed"
else
  echo "Test not passed"
fi
```

I want it to fail on the `false` statement and stop the execution of the function. But despite the `-e` option, the function doesn't stop when it's in the `if` statement. The result of this script is:

```
Should not be here
Test passed
```

I tried to use a subshell `( set -e ... )` but it doesn't have an effect, the function is still executed until the end.

How to stop the function execution on an error in the `if` statement?

**Update:** I need the `-e` option to be kept so that `(func); if []` variant is not an option.

**Update 2**: There are many commands in my real function and I don't want to make a mess checking the return value of each and every command. Just stop the execution on error in any of the commands. I've simplified the example just to demonstrate what I need.

PS: Changed the function name to not mess things.

Comment: It's because it's in an `if`. `set -e` is an inconsistent and unpredictable mess; see [BashFAQ #105: Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) BTW, `test` is the name of a rather important built-in shell command, so overriding it with a function is not a good idea.

Comment: `( test ); if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Test passed...` should work. And yeah, find a better name for your function.

Comment: Just renamed the example function. The `(func); if' variant doesn't work with the `-e` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following approach that doesn't mess my code with checking each and every line:

```bash
set -e

...

func() {(
  set -e

  ...
  command that fails
  echo "Should not be here"
)}

set +e
func; r=$?
set -e
if [ $r = 0 ]; then
  echo "Test passed"
else
  echo "Test not passed"
fi
```

This works as expected and only prints `Test not passed`. I can add any number of lines in the `func` and failure of any of them will break the whole function execution. And the whole script has the `-e` option set. Everything as I need with minimal code additions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to design your function so that it is robust even in the absence of an explicit `set -e`.

```
test () {
    false &&
    echo still here
}
```

And as multiple others have already pointed out, `test` is a really poor choice for the function name because it shadows the built-in command.

Answer (score -1):

From the Bash `man` page:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword, part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words, …

And it gets even worse:

> The `ERR` trap is not executed if the failed command is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or until `keyword`, part of the test in  an  `if`  statement, …

That said, one possible answer is: **Don’t call your function in the `if` statement.** For example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -uo pipefail

test_function() (
  trap return ERR
  false
  echo "Should not be here"
)

test_function
if (($?)); then
  echo "Test not passed"
else
  echo "Test passed"
fi
```

Differences:

- No `-E`; we don’t really need to inherit `ERR` `trap`s and the original script didn’t have any anyway.
- No `-e`; a bit of “manual” error handling may be needed in this case. One could (and perhaps should) enable/disable the option as needed (`set -e` by default, `set +e` in a few special places).
- `trap return ERR` has an effect similar to `set -e`, but only locally in the function.
- The function body is a subshell rather than just a compound command; that way `trap return ERR` stays local to the function. On the other hand, certain (ugly) tricks such as global state modification (using `declare -g` to add variables or `local -n` to “point” at them) won’t work. (Good riddance, in a way.)
- Note that a `return` statement without an argument passes through the status of the previous command, which may be a more valuable piece of information than (e.g.) a unified `return 1`. A quick example:  `blah() { (exit 7;); return; }; blah; echo $?`